# Typescript: Property does not exist on type 'never', but function works?

Tags: typescript

This is my code

```
sumDevices() {
let onlineDevicesArray = [];
let offlineDevicesArray = [];

for(let group of this.groups[this.selectedDeviceSource.id]){
  for(let device of group.devices){
    if(device.onlineState == "Online"){
      onlineDevicesArray.push(device.onlineState);
      this.onlineDevices = onlineDevicesArray.length;}
    else{
      offlineDevicesArray.push(device.onlineState);
      this.offlineDevices = offlineDevicesArray.length;
    }
  }
}
```

}

It gives an error on device.onlineState, but the function does work.

```
TS2339:Property 'onlineState' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

**Can anyone explain to me why its giving me this error?**

Comment: can you please provide definition of device.onlineState, typeof(device).

Comment: sometimes after there is a compilation error in the Ts code. The javascript generator does not run. This causes anything dependent on the generated js to use the last generated js. 
Which in your case will contain device.onlineState

Comment: @ParvSharma It's a device object and one of the properties is the onlineState which returns Online or Offline, if thats what you mean?

Comment: This peeves me so dang much. JavaScript/Typescript, the brackets typically do NOT start on new lines. I know it really doesn't matter, but seeing JavaScript/Typescript formatted like this hurts my brain -- and actually makes it harder for me to read your code and help.

Comment: @Pytth I've edited it. Is this clearer to you?

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays YES! Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to provide type for arrays, by default it is "never".
Something like this should work.

```
let onlineDevicesArray:number[] = [];
let offlineDevicesArray:any[] = [];
```

Comment: I've fixed it now, used a forEach instead of the second for loop. Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: You may have never type in group.devices declaration. group.devices = []; But as code gor Group is not shown, it is impossible to find place with never type.